# Set Excel spreadsheet values to wrap text automatically when inserting values from VBA form

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently inserting some values into an Excel spreadsheet via a VBA form. What I've done is working great so far but I was wondering if there was a way to set the text to automatically wrap in each cell?

As right now it seems like everything will just overlap with each other.

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set ws = Worksheets("main")
    Set rng1 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp)
    rng1.Offset(1, 0) = cbo_deptCode.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: As a once off just format column A as being wrapped text (via right-click, *Format Cells*, and check *Wrapped Text*)

Comment: Will this work even if a table is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
With rng1.Offset(1, 0)
    .Value = cbo_deptCode.Value
    .WrapText = True
End With
```

Comment: Doing this cell by cell is inefficient compared to just formatting the column beforehand